# feedforward fully connected neural network | matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, supervised-learning

I spent the past 3 hours trying to create a feed-forward neural network in matlab with no success. It's really confusing for me now.

I am trying to create the following neural network:

- The input layer has 122 features/inputs,
- 1 hidden layer with 25 hidden units,
- 1 output layer (binary classification),
- Input layer and Hidden layer have bias units (Please see the image below for a general idea)

[image]

But from my analysis of the `network` function, I can't understand how I am going to specify 25 hidden units or neurons in my single hidden layer, and how I can make all of the input layer neurons connected to these hidden unit.

```
net = network(numInputs,numLayers,biasConnect,inputConnect,layerConnect,outputConnect);
```

For example if I want to create a neural network with 5 inputs and 5 hidden units in the hidden layer (including the bias units) and make it fully connected. I am using this code:

```
net = network(5,1,1,[1 1 1 1 1],0,1);
```

which output this:

[image]

From my understanding my code has the following problems:

- There is no bias inputs in the input layer
- it's not a fully connected network (it's like one neuron is connected to only on hidden neuron)

So please, I have put my cards on the table, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suppose you are confusing the number of inputs/layers with their size:

- your network has ONE input, whose size is 122;
- your network has TWO layers:

  - 1st layer: hidden layer with 25 nodes (`W` is a 25 by 122 weight matrix);
  - 2nd layer: output layer with 1 node (`W` is a 1 by 25 weight matrix).

The following code does what you are trying to do:

```
% 1, 2: ONE input, TWO layers (one hidden layer and one output layer)
% [1; 1]: both 1st and 2nd layer have a bias node
% [1; 0]: the input is a source for the 1st layer
% [0 0; 1 0]: the 1st layer is a source for the 2nd layer
% [0 1]: the 2nd layer is a source for your output
net = network(1, 2, [1; 1], [1; 0], [0 0; 1 0], [0 1]);
net.inputs{1}.size = 122; % input size
net.layers{1}.size = 25; % hidden layer size
net.layers{2}.size = 1; % output layer size
net.view;
```

Which results in:

[image]

Try also `help network`, to have a look on how to set input data range, transfer functions and more.

Comment: Thank you, I am confused. But this opens a lot of questions for me, But I'll ask the important ones. Does the code you've provided consider the bias units? Meaning, after adding the bias nodes, W1 should be 25x123 matrix and W2 should be 1x26 matrix. The second question, I've already asked the Datascient community (look [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40275/multi-class-neural-networks-different-features) if you are interested): When you say "your network has ONE input, whose size is 122", does this mean I can have more than one inputs with different sizes a.k.a features?

Comment: @U.USer:    1) The bias weights are considered apart within the `network` object. The weights connecting the input to the 1st layer are in `net.IW{1}` (which is a 25x122 matrix), while the corresponding bias weights are stored in `net.b{1}` (which is 25x1). The weights having the 2nd layer as destination and the 1st layer as source are stored in `net.LW{2,1}` (1x25), while bias weights are in `net.b{2}` (1x1).     2) yes. You may have multiple user input "sources" and/or reentry from other layers (i.e. recurrent neural networks)